# Colorshceme en vim no funciona correctamente

Tags: windows, powershell, vim

Hola estoy usando powershell en windows terminal, funciona en el archivo de configuracion .vimrc pero no al editar un archivo,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando es otro archivo no funciona,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ejemplo en el console.log no funciona solo en function

Comment: tiene que ver con los colores o el tema del windows terminal, por eso no te funciona el tema de vim, windows terminal elimina el tema de vim

Comment: gracias lo voy a intentar

Comment: no me funciono intente en powershell y no me funciono

Comment: pues si, en windows es complicado, pero si usas el gvim (que es el vim con gui) te funciona de maravilla.

Comment: ya lo intente en gvim tambien pero y pasa lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

la lo resolvi agregando esto a mi init.vim

```
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polygot'
```